# Spring Integration DSL, PayloadTypeRouter, unsupported return type for router [class java.lang.Class]

Tags: spring-integration

I'd like to use `PayloadTypeRouter` as part of Spring Integration DSL as follows:

```
jmsFlowsUtils.jmsXmlInputFlow(queue, loggingChannel)
    .<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass, incomingMsg -> incomingMsg
            .subFlowMapping(SomeClass.class.getName(), firstFlow -> firstFlow
                    .<SomeClass>handle(handler1::handle))
                    // and so on
            .subFlowMapping(AnotherClass.class.getName(), secondFlow -> secondFlow
                    .<AnotherClass>handle(handler2::handle)))
                    // and so on
    .get();
```

After I send xml message into queue, SI complains with

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: 
Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; 
nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: 
unsupported return type for router [class java.lang.Class]
```

Any idea what workaround to apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.<Object, String>route(p ->  p.getClass().toString(), incomingMsg -> incomingMsg
```

or use Spring Integration Java DSL 1.2 already with Spring Integration `4.3.1`. The `Class<?>` as a routing key has been fixed in the https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4057.

With that you don't need to use `.toString()` for classes. The sample from project tests:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow payloadTypeRouteFlow() {
    return f -> f
            .<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass, m -> m
                    .channelMapping(String.class, "stringsChannel")
                    .channelMapping(Integer.class, "integersChannel"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Artem! Your answer helped. I only found 1.1.3.RELEASE version which works.